# JavaScript Regex exclude leading and trailing spaces, but maintain inner-spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

`'   hello world   '`

I would like to match groups `'   '`, `'hello world'`, and `'   '`

I can't figure out how to allow spaces in the middle of the regex, where they aren't anchored to end

My attempt (http://regex101.com) `/(^\s*)(.+)(\s*$)/g`

Comment: 1. Problem is underspecified. What should happen with `'     '`? 2. Why do you need this in a single regex?

Comment: It is very strange what you need it for. Surely `^(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)$` will work, but it might slow your code down significantly.

Comment: I don't know your exact use case, but what about simply using the `trim()` function? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: The use-case is irrelevant for this question, I need to match anything between the bounding spaces, but not the bounding spaces, if they exist

Comment: The usecase is not irrelevant. Define "*need to*".

Comment: When a user makes a selection on the page, I need to exclude newlines and spaces so that I'm not grepping for the wrong length and analyzing focusOffset and anchorOffset incorrectly. I would use trim and indexOf to compute the leading and trailing groups, but it makes more sense to get it in one shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 3 capturing groups:

```
/^(\s*)(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)(\s*)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s6dZgC/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\s*)`: Match & capture starting white space (zero or more)
- `(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)`: Match & capture middle string that may contain white spaces
- `(\s*)`: Match & capture ending white space (zero or more)
- `$`: End

Comment: the middle part doesn't seem as concise as it should be, I'm trying to understand it

Comment: It is not short because I made an attempt to make it efficient, without lot of backtracking.

Comment: ah, now I see why it's `\s+\S+` because if there is a space, another non-space is required after it

Comment: Yes that's right  as middle part must start and end with a non-space

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is always spaces_words_spaces:

```
"   hello world   ".match(/^(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)$/)
```

Prints:

```
["   hello world   ", "   ", "hello world", "   ", index: 0, input: "   hello world   "]
```

Comment: `.*?` or `.+?` may also work but will be very inefficient as the input string length grows.

Comment: `.*?` is non-greedy quantifier

Comment: I see, never used lazy vs greedy before, thought that was the same as `.?` but now I get it

Comment: I gave @anubhava the answer for performance and lack of back-tracking, but this is still good and I learned something, thank you